# How to get HTML5 videos in sync?

Tags: html, video, synchronization

You would say `video1.play();` followed by `video2.play();` would play the videos at the same time, but they have a smile delay. How can you remove that delay and keep them in sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first that both video's [readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) is larger than 3, to do that:

- register [canplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) event handlers for both videos
- check the ready state after registering the two handlers (in case [canplay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) was already triggered for the videos before the event handlers were registered)
- start the videos only when both of them are ready

The two videos still can get out of sync because of network issues, you could use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) to poll the [currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) properties of the videos and sync them (by setting the [currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime)) if they are too far apart.